# Create new table in SQLite with query result

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have this code in Java and i need to insert the result into new table. Is this possible with just editing this query?

```
  ResultSet result = stat.executeQuery("SELECT artist, COUNT(artist) AS countartist FROM table1 GROUP BY artist ORDER BY countartist DESC;");
```

Comment: `insert into some_table (col1, col2) select artist ...`

Comment: do i need to create the new table before?

Comment: You can do that or use `create table tab_name as select artist ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

ResultSet result = stat.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT artist, COUNT(artist) AS countartist FROM table1 GROUP BY artist ORDER BY countartist DESC");

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)"

Comment: Sorry, I put an extra parentheses. Try it now.

Comment: "java.sql.SQLException: query does not return ResultSet" could it be something with my code? previous query is working fine

Comment: It's not going to return a result set because it's essentially a command.